# Packaging legacy Fortran in Python. Is it OK to use setuptools and numpy.distutils?

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, setuptools, f2py

I am trying to make a python package distribution for some popular Fortran codes in my field.  I want it to use the most standard approach with a `setup.py` file.  The related qustion was helpful for learning [how to wrap Fortran extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932028/setup-py-for-packages-that-depend-on-both-cython-and-f2py?rq=1).

When using this approach, I noticed some confusing behavior when mixing `setuptools` and `numpy.distutils`.  Is it bad practice to mix the two?  As of 2015, it seems preferable to use `setuptools` as much as possible.

However, I would like to build `Fortran` extensions in a way that is compatible with `numpy.`  So I would like to import from `numpy.distutils` to get `Extension` and `setup`.

I'm using the following basic approach:

```
from setuptools.command.develop import develop
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension, setup

ext_modules=[Extension("my_package.fortran_mod", sources=['src/fortran_mod.f'])]

class MyDevelop(develop):
  def run(self):
    my_script()
    develop.run(self)

setup(
  ...
  ext_modules=ext_modules,
  cmdclass={'develop':MyDevelop})
```

This seems to work but I have questions.

1. Is it generally good practice to mix `setuptools` and `numpy.distribute`?
2. Does the order I import them matter?  Should I always import `setuptools` first?
3. Is there an official up-to-date tutorial for packaging extensions to `numpy`?  Perhaps even one with some discussion Fortran extensions?

---

### Some links

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4yB-8tB0J0

http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#interfacing-with-python

Comment: I'm not an expert in wrapping Fortran code - but I'm pretty experience with Cython. [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4yB-8tB0J0) from Scipy 2015 has a really nice section on successfully wrapping Fortran code - I suggest you take a look!

Comment: Thanks.  I really appreciate your comment.  That is new information for me and seems useful.  Could you list a few of the main advantages of writing the wrapper layer in Cython over standard Python.  Is it just faster? or is there some improved generality?  He stressed the `nogil` at one point.  Maybe this would be advantageous if the code I'm wrapping uses MPI?

Comment: What do you mean by standard Python? ``nogil`` is very important if you want to be able to delegate down to native code and make use of threading/multi-process. Your MPI example is a perfect time to release the GIL!

Comment: "Standard" isn't the right word I guess.  A package is either pure Python or it has extensions, and I'm already using extensions.  I have only used Fortran extensions so far.  I will need to wrap Fortran-MPI code soon, so if Cython lets me turn off the `gil` that is fantastic.  Thanks for sharing the video and bringing up this point.

Comment: @BeRecursive How does the GIL have anything common with MPI? MPI has separate processes so the lock should not come into play. Threads are different though.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Vladimir.

Comment: Compared to f2py, Cython would allow you to use [iso_c_binding](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html) in the Fortran code.Because f2py is mainly build for Fortran77 code, it lacks a lot of great Fortran90+ features, such as dynamic memory allocation. With Cython you have a much greater flexibility because your Fortran and Cython code can speak (almost natively) to eachother using iso_c_binding.

Comment: Following some of the earlier comments I would like to contribute two more options to your considerations. If you use "old" Fortran, then you could directly access your Fortran functions using `ctypes` (just take care of the function-names which, depending on your compiler, get a trailing underscore). Recently I have become a fan of [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) which allows you to write the entire Python module from C++, with the bonus advantage that the ancient Fortran code gets a modern front-end.

Comment: It appears that Cython provides a very flexible way to wrap FORTRAN programs.  Here is a working example of how to follow the Cython (with iso_c_binding) route: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404060/fortran-cython-workflow .

Comment: @Will Before you undertake your Fortran conversions are you positive they aren't already implemented in the SciPy low level Fortran interfaces? https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/blas.py also lapack.py you'd be hard pressed to write anything faster (I've tried with MKL and can only shave maybe microseconds (I.e. not statistically significant improvements)) Also have a look there they have some prewitten Cython test programs (dgemm does have a bug you can resolve by searching on a post of mine SciPy dgemm interface not working on mx1 1xn vectors)

Answer (score 3):

> This seems to work but I have questions.
>
> 1. Is it generally good practice to mix setuptools and numpy.distribute?
> 2. Does the order I import them matter? Should I always import setuptools first?
> 3. Is there an official up-to-date tutorial for packaging extensions to numpy? Perhaps even one with some discussion Fortran extensions?

1. You should not need to use numpy.distribute anymore.
2. ^^ Not necessary
3. Particularly for wrapping fortran code with numpy, there is the popular [f2py](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/). However I personally find the necessary code annotations redundant, because good fortran code contains all necessary information.

(*warning personal project plug below*)

Recently released is the cleaner [fmodpy](https://github.com/tchlux/fmodpy), which automatically generates all necessary wrapper code in an understandable and clean interface. It supports pre-Fortran90, but is best suited for Fortran90 and later. It could be used to generate a clean distribution along with the python interface of code (presuming users have gfortran installed).

Comment: The personal project plug is not problem, but this answer is.  Could you please reference the questions you are answering int the 1,2,3 above so that this *answer* can be actually read as is?